# XSLT to CSV with a key / value pair

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some XML output that I'd like to convert into CSV, but with the data containing a key/value pair it has proven most difficult. I have tried many iterations over many days and I finally need some help. This is the XML that needs to be converted with XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<status>
    <snapshot>
        <metrics>
            <entry>
                <key>time</key>
                <value>1001</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>bytes</key>
                <value>104</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>input</key>
                <value>13321</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>output</key>
                <value>11002</value>
            </entry>
        </metrics>
        <timestamp>2016-01-12T01:00</timestamp>
        <metrics>
            <entry>
                <key>time</key>
                <value>1002</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>bytes</key>
                <value>105</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>input</key>
                <value>13322</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>output</key>
                <value>11003</value>
            </entry>
        </metrics>
        <timestamp>2016-01-12T02:00</timestamp>
    </snapshot>
</status>
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
time,bytes,input,output,timestamp
1001,104,13321,11002,2016-01-12T01:00
1002,105,13322,11003,2016-01-12T02:00
```

=== Adding XSLT that I am using ===

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

    <xsl:key name="field" match="entry/*" use="name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', name())[1])]">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>

            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="/*/sObject">

            <xsl:variable name="property" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="$property/*">

                <xsl:variable name="value" select="." />
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

             </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>


     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A side note... I tried adapting a portion of XSLT code from @dnovatchev, but I'm having issues adapting it to a key value pair scenario.    `<xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[normalize-space(key)='foo']/value"/>`

Comment: Can one assume that every `metrics` has the same entries, in the same order, only with different values?

Comment: @shellter Adding code that I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your given example xml and informations, please try following **XSLT 1.0** This is a improved, simplified version with dynamic approach. If your XML changes slightly, you are not forced to change your stylesheet (eg. adding `entries`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="status snapshot"/>

    <xsl:template match="snapshot">

        <!-- generate the headline -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="metrics[1]/entry/key | timestamp[1]" mode="heading"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

       <!-- generate the content -->
        <xsl:for-each select="metrics">
            <xsl:for-each select="entry/value">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ',')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[name() = 'timestamp'][1]"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="metrics/entry/key" mode="heading">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ',')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="timestamp" mode="heading">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
time,bytes,input,output,timestamp
1001,104,13321,11002,2016-01-12T01:00
1002,105,13322,11003,2016-01-12T02:00
```

**Requirements:**

All `entry` and its childs are always present and the same.

Comment: that works perfectly. Thank you very much. May I add one wrinkle? If I were to add a timestamp to each of those two records how can I modify the xslt. I have been taking a few stabs at it by adding another xsl:for-each select="timestamp" block, but I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: see my improved version; please take note, your "accepted" answer is fully static. that is most of the time a bad thing. just working is not always the best.

Answer (score 0):

This is also for XSLT 1.0

Define the four required columns. Then pick only they key/value pairs that match. This way absent key/value pairs would be considered in the output and any additional pairs ignored. Delimiter and column names can be passed as parameters.

Disadvantage: no flexibility in case of changing key names.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:param name="del" select="','"/>
<xsl:param name="col1" select="'time'"/>
<xsl:param name="col2" select="'bytes'"/>
<xsl:param name="col3" select="'input'"/>
<xsl:param name="col4" select="'output'"/>
<xsl:param name="col5" select="'timestamp'"/>
<xsl:template match="/status/snapshot">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($col1, $del, $col2, $del, $col3, $del, $col4, $del, $col5, '&#10;')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="metrics">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(entry[key = $col1]/value, $del)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(entry[key = $col2]/value, $del)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(entry[key = $col3]/value, $del)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(entry[key = $col4]/value, $del)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(../timestamp[$pos], '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Also works great. Thanks! I edited my question to add the timestamp field. Any ideas on how to add that as another column? *timestamp* sits just outside the key/value pairs.